# JTextArea hidden until clicked in when added to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextarea, bots

What I'm trying to accomplish here is adding a JTextArea to my pre-existing JPanel. When I run the program, it does infact add it to the JPanel I'm looking for, but it puts the JTextArea behind the JPanel until I click in the area it should be. If I click in another JTextArea added to the same JPanel as the one I'm having issues with, then the entire JTextArea will appear.

```
 // Once program works as intended, use CardLayout to switch screens, rather than using JFrame with setVisible(true/false)
 // JPanels. Tutorial left on Stackoverflow with example code. 12/31/15


 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class UserInterface implements ActionListener 
 {

 JFrame screen; 
 JButton start, submit, help;
 JPanel UI,userWhite, passWhite;
 JLabel usrTxt, passTxt;
 JTextArea usrInput, passInput, console;

static String[] strings = new String[2]; //See getInformation() method
HELP runner = new HELP();

public static void main(String args[])
{
    UserInterface userinterface = new UserInterface();
    userinterface.uiSetup();
    userinterface.displaySetup();
    userinterface.inputSetup();
    userinterface.consoleSetup();
}

public void run()
{
    uiSetup();
    displaySetup();
    inputSetup();
    consoleSetup();
}


public void uiSetup()
{
    // This method sets up the initial interface which all other
    // elements within this program will be built off of

    screen = new JFrame("Bing Rewards Bot v.Development 1.0");
    screen.setVisible(true);
    screen.setSize(800, 600);
    screen.setResizable(false);
    screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    screen.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    UI = new JPanel();
    UI.setVisible(true);
    UI.setLayout(null);
    UI.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    screen.add(UI);
                                        // Buttons must me initialized here. If done in another method,
                                        // it can sometimes block JPanels from appearing. Fixed: 12/27/15
    start = new JButton("Start Bot");
    start.setVisible(true);
    start.setFocusable(false);
    start.setBounds(150,500,200,75);
    UI.add(start);

    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    submit.setVisible(true);
    submit.setFocusable(false);
    submit.setBounds(75,170,100,50);
    UI.add(submit);

    help = new JButton("HELP");
    help.setVisible(true);
    help.setFocusable(false);
    help.setBounds(455,500,200,75);
    help.setActionCommand("helpClicked");
    help.addActionListener(this);
    UI.add(help); 
}


public void displaySetup()
{
    // This method sets up the interface text

    usrTxt = new JLabel("Bing/Microsoft Account Username");
    usrTxt.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 16));
    usrTxt.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    usrTxt.setBounds(0,0,310,20); // Adjusts Absolute Size
    usrTxt.setLocation(25,50); // Sets Location
    UI.add(usrTxt);

    passTxt = new JLabel("Password");
    passTxt.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 16));
    passTxt.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    passTxt.setBounds(0,0,310,20);
    passTxt.setLocation(25,100);
    UI.add(passTxt);
}

public void consoleSetup()
{
    //TODO Appearing behind JPanel: UI

    console = new JTextArea("Bing Rewards Bot v.Development 1.1\nInterface Loaded Sucessfully. Awaiting User Input...");
    console.setSize(700,200);
    console.setLocation(25,260);
    console.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    console.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    console.setVisible(true);
    console.setEditable(false);
    // console.setText("01/02/16//:: Initalizing JTextArea()");
    UI.add(console);

}

public void inputSetup()
{
    // This method handles the User name and Password field setup


    userWhite = new JPanel();
    userWhite.setVisible(true);
    userWhite.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    userWhite.setLocation(25,70);
    userWhite.setSize(200,25);
    UI.add(userWhite);

    passWhite = new JPanel();
    passWhite.setVisible(true);
    passWhite.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    passWhite.setLocation(25,120);
    passWhite.setSize(200,25);
    UI.add(passWhite);

    usrInput = new JTextArea();
    usrInput.setBounds(0,0,200,18);
    usrInput.setLocation(25,75);
    usrInput.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    usrInput.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    UI.add(usrInput);

    passInput = new JTextArea();
    passInput.setBounds(0,0,200,18);
    passInput.setLocation(25,125);
    passInput.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    passInput.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    UI.add(passInput);

}

public void getInformation()
{
    // This method gets the information from the
    // JTextAreas in the inputSetup method and
    // stores it into an array called "strings"
    // ("strings" is initialized in the class)

    strings[0] = usrInput.getText();
    strings[1] = passInput.getText();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("helpClicked")) 
    {
        UI.setVisible(false);
        runner.helpSetup(screen);

    }
}
```

Also, is it required to add a scrolling pane to a JTextArea? I've never worked with JTextAreas before, so I figure I'd add it later once the program works as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I'm trying to accomplish here is adding a JTextArea to my pre-existing JPanel

Well, I don't know what part of the code you are talking about. We don't have time to read your entire code to understand the logic.

So all I can do is make general comments:

1) The basic code when adding component after a GUI is visible is:

```
panel.add( someComponent );
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

2) Don't use null layouts. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers for too many reasons to list here.

3) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most of you names are correct but some are not. Be consistent!!!

4) Components should be added to the frame BEFORE making the frame visible.

5) The GUI should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Maybe start with the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for basic Swing information with working demos that will show you how to better structure your code.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll be more specific next time. Didn't think to try .repaint(), but that's all it needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- Take `screen.setVisible(true);` and put it at the end of the `run`. If you need to dynamically update the UI, you will need to use `revalidate` followed by `repaint` to instruct the UI to update its layout information. If possible, make use of `CardLayout` to dynamically switch between multiple views, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details
- Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify